# JAVA Client and C# server Byte array issue

Tags: java, c#, android, arrays, tcp

We are working on making an android client that sends frame by frame video to a C# server using TCP. We send photos from our client as a byte array. However, in JAVA a byte array is signed but in C# it is unsigned. is there any solution to that? please keep in my mind I searched this issue for two days so I checked most resources online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C# you can use `sbyte`, which is signed.

Comment: C# can not receive a signed byte array from network stream. If there is a way share it :D

Comment: It does not matter if a byte is signed or unsigned (which it should not be of course) as a byte is just 8 bits. You will receive the same bits as Android sent. You can check easily by printing the value as hex. Handle them as you want. Cast them to what you want. Save them to file and it will be the same file as sent.

Comment: `We send photos from our client as a byte array.` You might explain what you mean by that. Are you just sending the file? I would think so.

Comment: I'm sending an image from my android client to be processed by a C# client. We send the photo as a byte array. but here is the catch, byte array in java is from -128 to 127. when sent the byte array from java and receive it in the server C# ignores the sign and takes the value, that's is our issue

Comment: is it clear now?